# DEM in the form .img to ASCII in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal

I have a DEM in the form of a .img file. I need to convert it to a .asc file, but when I try, it does not work and the file contains no data. I have used the gdal2xyz and raster translate tools in QGIS with the same result. However, when I convert to .csv, the data is there. But it has to be a .asc file. How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly are you doing, and what exactly happens? "Doesn't work" doesn't tell us much. And why do you need an .asc file? More details please on what are you trying to do.

Comment: is the file in the public domain?

Comment: When I use the QGIS plug-ins mentioned, a .asc file is produced but, as I said, it contains no data. Where the data should be, it just has NaN. I need a .asc file because the script I want to run requires a .asc file.